# Pytest conftest.py is called increasing number of times during repeated test execution

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, pytest

This is my `conftest.py`:

```
class ValueStorage:
    ime_rute = None
    web_driver = None


@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome"], scope="class")
def init_driver(request):
    start = datetime.now()
    tester = os.environ["USERNAME"]
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(filename=f'.\\Reports\\{date.today()}_duration.log'))
    if request.param == "chrome":
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        if Options.HEADLESS == 1:
            options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        ValueStorage.web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    if request.param == "firefox":
        ValueStorage.web_driver = webdriver.Firefox(GeckoDriverManager().install())
    request.cls.driver = ValueStorage.web_driver
    yield
    end = datetime.now()
    logger.info(
        f"{end}: --- DURATION: {end - start} --- ROUTE NAME: {ValueStorage.ime_rute} --- HEADLESS: {Options.HEADLESS} --- RUN BY: {tester}")
    ValueStorage.web_driver.close()
```

I'm running the tests from the command line using

```
pytest -k example -vv
```

(where "example" is the test name).

I wish to repeat the test multiple times, so I'm using `@pytest.mark.repeat(100)` decorator:

```
    @pytest.mark.repeat(100)
    @pytest.mark.develop
    def test_example(self):
        # test code
```

Output in the duration.log file will be like

```
2021-04-29 12:10:57.245345: --- DURATION: 0:00:24.612506 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3843-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:11:21.726882: --- DURATION: 0:00:24.364809 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3844-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:11:21.726882: --- DURATION: 0:00:24.364809 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3844-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:11:57.758704: --- DURATION: 0:00:35.897821 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3845-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:11:57.758704: --- DURATION: 0:00:35.897821 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3845-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:11:57.758704: --- DURATION: 0:00:35.897821 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3845-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:12:28.073752: --- DURATION: 0:00:30.255046 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3846-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:12:28.073752: --- DURATION: 0:00:30.255046 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3846-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:12:28.073752: --- DURATION: 0:00:30.255046 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3846-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
2021-04-29 12:12:28.073752: --- DURATION: 0:00:30.255046 --- ROUTE NAME: 210429-3846-RT-JDoe --- HEADLESS: 1 --- RUN BY: tester1
```

So, what is happening is that the `logger.info()` line writes to log once for the first test run, twice for the second one, three times for the third and so on.

I tried changing scope of the pytest fixture to 'class', but then I'm getting that line logged only after the test has been run 100 times.

I want to get the `logger.info()` write to log after each test execution once. What do I need to do?

Comment: You add a new logging handler each time your `init_driver` is executed, so for each new test class, each log will be made by one more handler. You need to add a handler only once (for example, in a session scoped fixture).

Comment: I cannot use session scope. I get "AttributeError: cls not available in session-scoped context". Is there another way?

Comment: I meant for the logger, but you also can check if the handler is already added using `logging.Logger.hasHandlers` (see the linked answer above).

Comment: Thanks, the linked question was helpful.